# Configure Hazelcast Near cache feature for specific IMAP OR ILIST in Hazelcast Client

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to configure Hazelcast Near Cache Feature for specific Imap OR IList but I am not able to find how to do it Hazelcast Document dont have clear indication of if it is possible or not.

We are using Hazelcast 3.9 but there is no issue for us to upgrade if Hazelcast updated version provide this feature.

We are using standalone setup of Hazelcast.

Is it possible to configure such thing in Hazelcast ?
OR
any alternative ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Near-cache is available for IMap but not for IList

For IMap, see [here](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/performance/near-cache#configuring-near-cache).

You can configure a near-cache on a client or on a server.

It's available on 3.9, so you don't need to upgrade for that reason, but it's a good idea in general not to use old software.